# Unresolved reference: frame_layout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm facing with problem "Unresolved reference: frame_layout".
It is written here:

```
  fun replaceFragment(fragment:Fragment, istransition:Boolean){
    val fragmentTransition = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    if (istransition){
        fragmentTransition.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_out_right,android.R.anim.slide_in_left)
    }
    fragmentTransition.add(R.id.frame_layout,fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName).commit()
}
}
```

It doesnt show any problems in project, but when I build it, here is an error.

There is activity_main.xml where I get frame_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check for the `import {YOUR_PACKAGE}.R`

import of `R` must refer to the same module where your `activity_main.xml` placed.

For Example: `com.example.android` is your `app:` module package

In this place, your import should be `import com.example.android.R`

or

You can directly add  `{YOUR_PACKAGE}.R.id.frame_layout`

```
    fun replaceFragment(fragment:Fragment, istransition:Boolean) {
            val fragmentTransition = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        
            if (istransition) {
                 fragmentTransition.setCustomAnimations(
                       android.R.anim.slide_out_right, 
                       android.R.anim.slide_in_left
                ) 
            }
            fragmentTransition.add({YOUR_PACKAGE}.R.id.frame_layout,fragment)
                  .addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
                  .commit()
        
  }
```